# Filter by Post Type

Tags: php, post-type

I'm trying to figure out how to filter the posts returned by post type. I have a list of checkboxes of my different post types, and using that, I've gotten an array of the post types wanted;

```
$contentTypes = explode(',', $_POST['contents']);
```

Which gives me this:

```
Array ( [0] => post-type1 [1] => post-type2 [2] => post-type3 [3] => post-type4 [4] => post-type5 );
```

When I set the $args for post_type I want to check it against $contentTypes and only show the ones that are in my array.

I may not have explained this very well. But what would be the best way to do this? If I need to rework what I've done so far that's fine too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WP_Query for that :

```
$contentTypes = explode(',', $_POST['contents']);
$qry = new WP_Query( array( 
'post_type' => $contentTypes
));

if( $qry->have_posts() ){
while( $qry->have_posts() ) {

$qry->the_post()
// Your code

}

}
```

Here is the [docs] ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query ) for WP_Query